# Alternative to using a switch statement C++

Tags: c++, arrays, switch-statement

I have about 40 cases within a `switch` statement. The value it is checking for is a number that is two inputs from the user concatenated, so if they enter 3 and 4, it passes 34 to the `switch` statement. Every `switch` statement passes that value to another function, which then returns a footage length depending on the concatenated value. What would be a better way to do this?

I was thinking some sort of array which I can `for` loop through to find the value I want?

Edit: Code snippet

```
void calcFootages2(const int z) {
    std::cout << "\n\nThe value of Z: " << z;
    switch (z) {
        default:
            std::cout << "\nYour input of " << z << " was invalid or something went wrong, please retry.";
            locChoose();
            break;
        case (12):
            std::cout << "\nThis will require a jumper " << calcFootages3(z) << " feet long.";
            break;
        case (21):
            std::cout << "\nThis will require a jumper " << calcFootages3(z) << " feet long.";
            break;
        case (23):
            std::cout << "\nThis will require a jumper " << calcFootages3(z) << " feet long.";
            break;
        case (32):
            std::cout << "\nThis will require a jumper " << calcFootages3(z) << " feet long.";
            break;
        case (34):
            std::cout << "\nThis will require a jumper " << calcFootages3(z) << " feet long.";
            break;
    }
}
```

the calcfootages function -

```
int calcFootages3(const int x) {
        if (x == 12 || x == 21) {
            return 10;
        }
        else if (x == 23 || x == 32) {
            return 11;
        }
    }
```

So the return 11 will eventually be the correct footage length, which then passes it back to the switch statement so it can display it to the user. I took away most of the statements as they are all the same pretty much.

I hope I formatted the code correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  We really need to see your code in order to help you.

Comment: I recommend you splitting this large text into paragraphs for readability.

Comment: `switch` may be the best you can do. Hard to be sure without code though. Look for patterns you can exploit.

Comment: What prevents you from calculating the "footage length" in a general way from "the concatenated value"?

Comment: PS: We are not interested if you are a programmer or not etc. Remove this junk from the post.

Comment: Apologies for the long paragraph. So the jist of this program is to get fiber jumper footage lengths between two cabinets that are next to each other. That is why there are so many case statements, because I only want to find footages for cabinets next to each other. I will post a code snippet.

Comment: You can "program the computer to do the same thing as you would do it by hand".

Comment: Posted some code snippets, shortened them down. Ed Heal, I am not interested if you are not interested. Please leave if you aren't going to contribute, thank you. @Alf I'm not sure, like I said I don't have much experience, but the reason I did it the way I did is because each cabinet I assign a value (1 - 20), that the user then chooses via input. I concat those two values they enter, to get something like 109 (for 10 and 9) or 1819 (for 18 and 19). I want this program to only allow a user to calculate footages for cabinets next to each other. Hope that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: All of your cases are the same..... why do you have a switch statement at all?

Comment: Alternatively, why have the `calcFootages()` method? You can just hardwire the footage into each switch case.

Comment: Every single `case` does exactly the same thing so it looks like you can remove the switch entirely and just call the function.

Comment: @NickAdams - Ed is trying to help you write a good question people will want to answer. I suggest listening to advice instead of attacking.

Comment: because depending on the case, it will pass that same number to the other function which calculates the footage (or it will eventually, right now it just returns a number so I can verify it is working), then that footage is returned back into the cout statement so that the user can see what their jumper footage should be.

Comment: @Krease he said it in a hostile way, he could have said: "Welcome to Stack Overflow. Since you are new, you should know that usually you want your questions to be concise and be easily answered; you adding in details about your lack of programming experience is not needed and you should remove it. As to your question, you could try..." instead of being hostile and just telling me to 'remove that junk'. Thanks.

Comment: Uhm, I forgot to remove my close vote after code was added. So now it's inconsistent with having posted an answer. But I think re-opening would be ungood.

Comment: @Galik how would you suggest I go about that? I wanted to avoid nesting a lot of if statements, which this way avoids. Would it be better to just add the footages if statements to the cases?

Comment: @NickAdams `or it will eventually` We can't debug your code if you're posting incorrect code. Given the code you've posted now, the switch is wholesomely unnecessary. If that's not accurate, please post code that accurately indicates your desires.

Comment: @NickAdams I can't post my answer now but I would likely do what `Cheers and hth. - Alf` answered below. My answer was going to offer an alternative where you can *gang* the `case` statements. Look at the very bottom of this page for an example of calling the same function for several different `case:` values: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Comment: @Galik thanks for the reply anyway, I used what Cheers and hth. - Alf suggested and it worked perfectly. I am going to read up on what you posted just for future reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can separate the checking of valid spec and footage calculation, e.g. like so:

```
std::vector<int> const valid_spec = {12, 21, 23, 32, 34};

if( find( valid_spec.begin(), valid_spec.end(), z ) == valid_spec.end() )
{
    cout << "Your input of " << z << " was invalid or something went wrong, please retry.";
}
else
{
    cout << "This will require a jumper " << calcFootages3(z) << " feet long.";
}
```

Comment: This looks like it would be way better, thank you! I've never used vector<int> before, but I can read up about it. Thank you for giving me somewhere to start, I appreciate it. So all the valid numbers can go into the valid_specs variable, but how do I pass the specific number (eg 32) to the calcFootages3() function? I see you have a z variable inside the if statement, but I am not sure what that does. If you don't want to explain, that is fine, but it would be a great help. Thanks again for this.

Comment: I think I get part of it. So you make a vector, which is like an array it seems, and then you use the if statement to see if z is in the vector, and if it is not spit out the error, otherwise, pass z to the calcFootages() function. Is that basically right?

Comment: In this case, you could also use `std::array<int, 5>`, which, unlike `std::vector<int>`, can be `constexpr`.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much! Switch statement can be removed!